# angular popover with html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

Which is the correct way to use `popver-html` directive?
I'd like to show an image through HTML `img` tag into my popover angular-bootstrap.
I've created a scope variable `$scope.html = "<img src=\""+$scope.mysrc+"\"></img>"` and I've put it into my directive

`<span popover-html="{{html}}" popover-title="......." popover-trigger="mouseenter"><a href="#">{{title}}</a></span>`

but I've this error:

> Uncaught Error: [$parse:syntax] [ERROR popover-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=%3C&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=1&p3=%3Cimg%20src%3D%22https:%2F%2Fs3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com%2Fstatic.screenweek.it%2Fmovie%2F2561%2Fposter%2Fita%2Foriginal.jpg%3F1278079214%22%3E%3C%2Fimg%3E&p4=%3Cimg%20src%3D%22https:%2F%2Fs3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com%2Fstatic.screenweek.it%2Fmovie%2F2561%2Fposter%2Fita%2Foriginal.jpg%3F1278079214%22%3E%3C%2Fimg%3E)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/5hoRzTfJVlTzoibdV30k?p=preview) guiding you how to put an image within a popover. Look for "`Dynamic Popover`" button
First of all, you need to [sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) your `HTML` which you are writing in your `JS`.

So, your JS goes like this:

`$scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml("<img src=\""+$scope.mysrc+"\"></img>");`

This will ensure your HTML is safe to be parsed as HTML. Don't forget to inject `ngSanitize` in your app as dependency.

Now, in your view, instead of using
`popover-html="{{html}}"` , you need to use `popover-html="html"`. Note that you are passing an expression to this popover.

Comment: OK it was what I was finding but I've some trouble with image loading because tooltip template is rendered before image, at the first time this is a problem for dimensions of it